# Fatal error: Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in PHP

Tags: laravel-5, php-5.6

I am running PHP 5.6 & Laravel 5.6 version project. When I clone it from github repo & run "composer install or composer update". It throws me following error.

`PHP Fatal error:  Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 85`

Is it the problem with dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

The laravel version number is unrelated to the minimum php version required. Laravel 5.6 requires php 7.1.3 or greater

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6#server-requirements

Comment: i am facing same error but using laravel 4.2 and php 5.6 can you suggest me what was the issue